# Displaying a log's add speed

Tags: unix, sed, grep, pipe, tail

I'm currently tailing a nginx access log, with a simple tail command.

```
tail -f access.log
```

I would like to be able to display the current average speed per second / minute of entries added to that log.
Is that possible to do it using simple by using tail and pipe-ing to another command (grep,  sed, wc), or do i need to think of another way of getting this data?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the number of lines per second continuously updated in real time, use the [`pv`](http://www.ivarch.com/programs/pv.shtml) utility:

```
tail -f -n 0 access.log | pv -lr > /dev/null
```

Note that `pv` continuously writes updates to a terminal until it runs out of input.  If you just want a snapshot of the rate at which lines are being added, things get a little more complicated.  Here's my stab at it (with a five-second sample time):

```
tail -f -n 0 access.log 2>/dev/null | perl -e '$SIG{ALRM} = sub { print $x/5.0; exit(0) }; alarm 5.0; while(<>) { $x++ }'
```